How can I make my swiper slides clickable, so I can additionally slide through my slides by clicking on them?
I have been trying to make my swiper slides work onClick in Angular but I have found no solution. In the swiper documents there is no mention of it either. I have 2 divs that work like slides from left to right and back in order to show additional data to the client. Just swiping works with no problem, but when trying to add clickable option on the slide I can't find any solution. It should works like this: I have 2 div slides that move from left to right and back. Instead of only swiping it, I would like to make them clickable so if someone doesn't want to swipe it can also click on the slide an it will slide itself to the next slide. Then if you want to go back to the first slide you click again on the second slide and it will slide again to the same position as it was before. Does anybody have any suggestions?
    import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



    @Component({
      selector: 'wa-userdisplay',
      standalone: true,
      imports: [],
      template: `
        
      <swiper-container loop="false" slides-per-view="1">
        <swiper-slide class="infotitleboxleft" (click)="onSlideNext()">
          <div class="infotitleboxleft">
            
          </div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide class="infotitleboxleft" (click)="onSlidePrev()">
          <div class="infotitleboxright">
            
          </div>
        </swiper-slide>
      </swiper-container> 
            
      `,
      styles: `
        
      .infotitleboxleft {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 9vh;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 62px;
      max-height: 78px;
    }
    .infotitleboxright {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 9vh;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 62px;
      max-height: 78px;
      gap: 1vh;
    }

      `,
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })

    export class WAUserDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('swiperContainer') swiperContainer: any;

      ngOnInit(): void {
        // initialize swiper
        this.swiperContainer.nativeElement.swiper_init();
      }

      onSlideNext() {
        this.swiperContainer.nativeElement.swiper_slideNext();
      }
      onSlidePrev() {
        this.swiperContainer.nativeElement.swiper_slidePrev();
      }
    }

